# i need to override the Magento\Customer\Api\AccountManagementInterface using plugin or preference after that overide will magento call the events

Tags: magento2

i need to override  rest api the  Magento\Customer\Api\AccountManagementInterface  using plugin or preference  after that  overide will magento call the events obsevers email trigger deafult magento will work or need to create it suggestion and examples

Comment: Do you want override or you want to create plugin? Because both the things are diffrent.